# How tall is a standard LEGO minifigure?

Tags: building, minifigures, size

Sometimes I build towns of LEGO buildings, and occasionally the minifigures will get stuck in a low roof or underhang (pun intended). Does anyone know the height of a standard LEGO person in bricks as well as inches/centimeters? Also, does a standard LEGO cap affect the minimum roof height of a LEGO building?

Comment: Already answered: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/666/what-are-the-practical-bounds-of-a-minifigure