# How to pose figs in LeoCAD?

Tags: minifigures, cad

I’m new to LeoCAD. I find it’s easy to add regular minifigs or Technic figures to a model, but I can’t find a way to pose them. For instance I could build a car and add a driver, but the figure is standing up by default and I can’t find a way to bend its legs so it can sit in the car. Are figures not poseable?

Comment: They are [certainly posable in LDraw](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/672/56) so I would assume the same holds for LeoCAD.